# Need to add row above the headers of Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have a dataframes, I need to add 8 rows above the header of dataframe, I am sharing dataframe and the desired output

### Dataframe:-

```
   Toll     No.     Vr.name
   245      2487    XR
   145      3754    MY
   55       7356    DF
   65       4487    DF
   28       7785    MY
   47       8235    XR
   87       2468    PQ
   75       9735    GR
   98       6486    TY
   240      1023    PQ
```

### rows need to be added

```
    Car      8425
    Booth No 24
    Toll TR. Mr.XYZ
    Date     05-JAN-22
    Amt      123
    Time     11:02:01
    Mode     QR
    Tag      YES
```

What Needed :-

1. Want to add rows in dataframe above the header of dataframe.
2. No. of rows may increase in some cases.

### Desired Output

```
   Car      8425
   Booth No 24
   Toll TR. Mr.XYZ
   Date     05-JAN-22
   Amt      123
   Time     11:02:01
   Mode     QR
   Tag      YES

   Toll     No.     Vr.name
   245      2487    XR
   145      3754    MY
   55       7356    DF
   65       4487    DF
   28       7785    MY
   47       8235    XR
   87       2468    PQ
   75       9735    GR
   98       6486    TY
   240      1023    PQ
```

Comment: Do you want to write this desired output in an excel or csv? What is the end-goal?

Comment: This is not possible in pandas. There is nothing "above the header". Maybe you're thinking about a spreadsheet program?

Comment: @MayankPorwal, Final goal is to get CSV or excel but before I need to pick data from different file for that I am using pandas. That's why I need to add rows above header.

Comment: @mozway, firstly we were doing that manually in spreadsheet, but now we are changing process, but we can't change the output file format. those rows are needed in output.

Comment: Can you store the data separately, for example the table as a pandas data frame, and the stuff above the header as key-value pairs in a (separate) dictionary? Print each data structure to a separate file and then concatenate the files (`cat dictionary_output data_frame_output > final_output`). This way, the data are easy to manipulate, easy to understand, and is kept modular.

Comment: Hey, @TimurShtatland your idea worked for me. I did the same as you said and I directly  appended both the datasets in CSV file. Thanks for your Valuable thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a separate datframe of rows, now I have two dataframes.

### DF -

```
    Car      8425
    Booth No 24
    Toll TR. Mr.XYZ
    Date     05-JAN-22
    Amt      123
    Time     11:02:01
    Mode     QR
    Tag      YES
```

### DF2:-

```
   Toll     No.     Vr.name
   245      2487    XR
   145      3754    MY
   55       7356    DF
   65       4487    DF
   28       7785    MY
   47       8235    XR
   87       2468    PQ
   75       9735    GR
   98       6486    TY
   240      1023    PQ
```

### Code to add both dataframe in CSV :-

```
with open((file_name), 'w',newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
       writer.writerow(row)
    writer.writerow(New_out)
    for index1,row1 in df2.iterrows():
       writer.writerow(row1)
```

I directly write both the dataframe in CSV file.

### Outtput I got:-

```
   Car      8425
   Booth No 24
   Toll TR. Mr.XYZ
   Date     05-JAN-22
   Amt      123
   Time     11:02:01
   Mode     QR
   Tag      YES
   Toll     No.     Vr.name
   245      2487    XR
   145      3754    MY
   55       7356    DF
   65       4487    DF
   28       7785    MY
   47       8235    XR
   87       2468    PQ
   75       9735    GR
   98       6486    TY
   240      1023    PQ
```